# Parent and subreport parameter boxes missing

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, parent-child

There is a parent report and a subreport. Both show parameters when called independently. But when the subreport is called from the parent the parameter boxes are not shown. And when it returns to the parent also the parameter boxes are missing. I want the parameter boxes from both the parent and the subreport to be always available. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible using the action "go to report". There is a small button in the centre above the report which will show/hide the parameter pane but that's it. The only way to do it (AFAIK) is to open the drill-thru report via a URL where you can specify whether the parameters are visible or not.

Comment: @Alan: I made it work calling a url with parameters so the parameter boxes are shown. But then there is no back button. Is it necessary to pass all the parent parameters to the subreport and then place a link there to the parent? Because if I just hit backspace it goes back to the parent with the default parameters and I want the caller parameterized report.

Comment: That's the problem. If you don't use the GO to report action, the back to parent button is not shown. It's really not as simple as it shoudl be! The only thing I can think of is to open the report via a URL in a new window. You just need to edit the url you generate so it looks like this..`javascript:void(window.open('[existing url inside single quotes here]','_blank'))`

Comment: @Alan: It works and looks kind of ok. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer just in case somebody else is looking for the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible using the action "go to report". There is a small button in the centre above the report which will show/hide the parameter pane but that's it.

The only way to do it (AFAIK) is to open the drill-thru report via a URL where you can specify whether the parameters are visible or not.

However, if you take this approach, the SSRS toolbar 'back  to parent' button will not be available, meaning you only have the browser's back button. Using the browser's back button will reset the parent report back to default parameters.

To get around this, you can use a bit of JavaScript to open the drill-thru report in a new window.

Use the 'go to URL' option and set the URL expression to something like ..

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & [existing url here] & "','_blank'))"
```