# How to link to other Report with shown parameter panel?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report. Inside this report I have a link to another report. If I click on this link then I land on the second report but my parameter panel are not shown by default. Is it possible that the parameter panel is showed automaticaly without expanding it?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parent and subreport parameter boxes missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064376/parent-and-subreport-parameter-boxes-missing)

Comment: There is no solution right.

Comment: There is a solution in the answer I pointed you at